# jQuery to allow navigate across sections and pages (ascensor.js?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, navigation

I have been trying to find a jQuery plugin that allows me to navigate through different pages. Although ascensor.js fairly does what I am trying to achieve, I am not aiming at creating a single-page website. A good example of what the site would look like is http://goo.gl/ZQ8L3T, which divides the page in different sections.

I would like to achieve a navigation system that navigates within the sections of one page horizonztally (also using the left and right arrow keys) and within the multiple pages of the website in a vertical manner (then again, that would also have to work when pressing both the up and down arrow keys).

I am not sure my jQuery skills allow me to modify the ascensor.js in order to make that happen. I honestly do not know if this could be achieved somehow. I am really at a loss here so would love to get some feedback/hints/help from the SO community.

Thanks in advance.
Cheers!

Comment: Is this similar to what you are looking for? fullPaje.js: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

Comment: I have to admit this is rather similar to what I am trying to achieve. Thank you, Alvaro. I'm afraid this will be of great help. ;)

Comment: Hey Alvaro, I have been checking the markup of your demo version and there is something I just can't seem to get right. In the menu, the different links take you to different pages as expressed by the 'href' value. However, those links retrieve the information included in the designated `<div>`'s where the value of `data-anchor`corresponds to what I thought was another html page. 

Would you be able to clarify this for me, please? I have done some research about data-anchor but haven't found anything that is relevant to the point. 

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `data` is an HTML 5 tag. You can create the tag you want preceded by `data`, for example: `data-example`, `data-demo`...etc. It is usually used as a way to save a value instead o using classes or other attributes such as `href`. It is used internally for the plugin. The anchor links (#) are usually used to move scroll the user to a certain part of the page. There are not multiple HTML pages, only one with different sections. Did you answer your question?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I read as well the explanation provided on github and it is all much more clear. What I would like to achieve is just that, several HTML pages, with fullscreen horizontal sliders just on certain pages. (Just what you have on the example, except the links on the menu really link to a page different than the homepage. I am doing this because I don't want all the content to load at the same time and also to keep track of the different pages). Any idea how I could achieve that effect?

Comment: You would need to load the content by ajax probably. You could use the `afterLoad` callback for it. To load each section content just after the user slides to the section.

Comment: Would this not have an affect on the loading time of the website? What I am trying to say is... I would like to have the content of the different pages (since I aim to have a big -if not great- number of pages). Is this by no means achievable? 

(I know your code covers is very thorough and offers many features and possibilities. It is really neat. But I am trying to build a blog-like structure with my code, based on articles, so I am not sure what's the best way to go). 

I would definitely appreciate some recommendations.

Comment: As I said, the only way would be to load your content by ajax. You can load content or even images on the fly when the user reaches the desired section. This way, there's not gonna be any impact on the initial load of the site.